# Make a form editable that base on a query

Tags: ms-access

My situation is this:

[image]

I have a editable table: t [id,a,b]

[[image]]

And a query: q

```
SELECT t.id AS t_id, IIf(t.a="",IIf(t.b="","<no data>",t.b),t.a) AS x FROM t;
```

[image][image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cg4L.png)

Now I build a form, where I add the q to t. The datasource is:

```
SELECT t.id, q.x, t.a, t.b FROM t LEFT JOIN q ON t.id = q.t_id
```

[image]

The Problem: The form is not editable.

[image]

How can I make the form editable?

**A solution would be to don't use a query and a join. But this is not my question:**

[image]

The Form is editable:

[image]

Comment: The columns from t should be editable (a, b). Check if you can edit them when opening the query directly (in datasheet view).

Comment: And see: [Dealing with Non-Updateable Microsoft Access Queries](http://www.fmsinc.com/Microsoftaccess/query/non-updateable/index.html) and [Allen Browne: Why is my query read-only?](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html)

Comment: A form is normally used to enter/edit data for a single table. Which table do you want to edit? Why do you use a complex query?

Comment: June7, the query calculates a value based on the row of the table. I want to display the value and have the table editable. I could do it without a query and calculate the value without using a join, but I need it in more than on place. So I don't want to repeat the code.